# PHP JSON response with wrong initial quotes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've a ajax request example:

```
$( "#searchMonitor" ).autocomplete({
    source:baseUrl + "util/searchMonitor",
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $('input[id="searchMonitor"]').val(ui['item'].label);

        /// needs 'cause we need label and not ID on textbox
        event.preventDefault();
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('input[name="userId"]').val(ui['item'].value);
        $('input[id="searchMonitor"]').val(ui['item'].label);
        log(ui);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Everything works fine... the request is sended to server and the response is 200 but with one problem.

```
   ''[{"label":"Kevin Kouketsu","value":"1"},{"label":"Kevinkouketssu","value":"46"},{"label":"Kevinkouketssu","value":"47"},{"label":"Kevinkouketssu","value":"48"}]
```

This '' is not normal and did not happen...

```
public function searchMonitor() {
    $search = strtolower($this->input->get('term'));

    $user = $this->users->getUserByName($search);
    $row_set = array();
    foreach ($user as $row){
        $new_row['label']=(stripslashes($row['nome']));
        $new_row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['id']));
        $row_set[] = $new_row; //build an array
    }

    echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
}
```

PHP code...
And every ajax request return with '' ...

Comment: Do you have '' outside your PHP tags somewhere?

Comment: @Devon no, and not happen with this function only... its with any json_encode .. A week ago everything works fine.

Comment: Why on Earth are you using `stripslashes` and `htmlentities` on strings destined for JSON?

Comment: @Phil that's not the problem but.. I should use which one? I have another json responses with same problem

Comment: _"its with any json_encode"_ <- can you verify this? Create / upload a `json-test.php` file containing only `<?= json_encode(['foo' => 'foo', 'bar' => 1, 'baz' => true]) ?>` and test the result

Comment: @shepher in regards to using `stripslashes` / `htmlentities`, I wouldn't use either... `$row_set[] = ['label' => $row['nome'], 'value' => $row['id']];`

Comment: response was: `''{"foo":"foo","bar":1,"baz":true}` with problem too. Code: 
    `public function teste() {
        echo json_encode(['foo' => 'foo', 'bar' => 1, 'baz' => true]);
    }`

Comment: @shepher and there's absolutely nothing else in that `json-test.php` file? Change it to just `<?= 'this is a test' ?>`. Do you still see the quotes in the rendered output?

Comment: @Phil omfg, i found the problem. In my custom.php has the quotes I mentioned and I do not know why they are there! And i found just 'cause you give me this idea to test the echo. Thanks man!

Comment: I'm confused. What `custom.php`? What does that have to do with the test file you created? Glad you got it sorted though

Comment: Its a MVC project with Codeigniter. `Custom.php` is on autoload and when I have a ajax request, the autoload is called too